# Update Bootstrap tab from Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap

According to the bootstrap docs you can activate a tab programatically from JavaScript; for example:

```js
const triggerEl = document.querySelector('#myTab button[data-bs-target="#profile"]')
bootstrap.Tab.getInstance(triggerEl).show()
```

I want to be able to do this from an Angular component. What I have so far is this:

```js
redirectTab(): void {
  const tab = document.querySelector(`#TabCtl button[data-bs-target="#nav-ett"]`);
  (window as any)["bootstrap"].Tab.getInstance(tab).show();
}
```

That `(window as any)["bootstrap"]` sticks out like a sore thumb; I'm sure there must be a better way to access bootstrap's APIs from Angular components.

This code doesn't work on first attempt and throws:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'show')

But if you click around the tabs and then try again, it works. Any ideas on a better way to do this?

Edit: ng-bootstrap is **not** the answer!

Answer (score 1):

There is a completely different approach to use packages like [ng-bootstrap's nav](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/nav/overview) or [ngx-bootstrap tabs](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/tabs?tab=overview) that offer a clean and out of the box solutions.

Comment: I meant to mention in the question that ng-bootstrap wasnt an option. It comes with it's own problems, and I find more often than not, it's a hassle to use.

Answer (score 0):

simply `triggerEl.click();`

```
const triggerEl = document.querySelector('#myTab button[data-bs-target="#profile"]')
triggerEl.click();
```